# Why does cloudflare block cookies from heroku server?

Tags: node.js, heroku, cookies, deployment, cloudflare

I am using nodejs server deployed on heroku and client deployed on vercel. Both are using freenom domain and connected to cloudflare.
I try to set cookie with these options:

```
path:'/',
sameSite:'none',// tried lax too
domain: (here is my cloudflare heroku domain - api.example.com)
```

I also use `app.set('proxy ...',1)` (writing from mobile phone, forgot second word in setting, but it is correct for sure in code.

When I go straight to heroku app page, in graphql playground it sets cookie with no problem at all. But when I go to cloudflare domain `api.example.com/graphql` or `web.example.com`
I don't receive any cookies in response. Only cloudflare cookies. There is no Set-Cookie or anything else.

I need to store redis cookie for using authorized methods, but it let's me to log in, but because cookie doesn't set, it logs me out on refresh.

Comment: Did you try to see if you could get the cookie and add it back using a cloudflare worker? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49428779/cloudflare-workers-check-for-cookie-add-headers-set-cookie

Comment: did you find a solution ?